# Telegrams from Unknown City that Gets Destroyed by Mist

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A visiting science fiction author, James D. Macdonald, showed a writing group at my school this story when I was in 7th/8th grade (around 1996-1997) and I can't remember the title or the author but it's always stayed with me and I'd love to find out more about it.

The gist of the story is that someone starts a job working for a news service, receiving telegrams or teletypes or similar written communiques. Pretty soon he starts receiving telegrams from a city that doesn't show up on any map, name kinda reminds me of Xanadu or something similar. The employee reads these telegrams as they describe a kind of mist enveloping this city; and to cut a short story short, the city is ultimately destroyed and no more word is received.

Really sorry if this is vague, doesn't leave much to go on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

["The Night Wire"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?86054), a short story by [H. F. Arnold](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?18253), text available [here](http://doyleandmacdonald.com/l_nightw.htm), audio [here](http://pseudopod.org/2013/10/18/pseudopod-356-the-night-wire/). The city is Xebico.

How I found it: I cheated. I emailed [James D. MacDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_D._Macdonald) and he was kind enough to answer me. He says you have a heck of a memory. The story is available many places on the web; I linked to the copy at MacDonald's web site.

An excerpt from the story:

> The first wire was running out the usual sort of stuff and I just looked over it hurriedly. Then I turned to the second pile of copy. I remembered it particularly because the story was from a town I had never heard of: "Xebico." Here is the dispatch. I saved a duplicate of it from our files:
>
> "Xebico, Sept 16 CP BULLETIN
>
> "The heaviest mist in the history of the city settled over
> the town at 4 o'clock yesterday afternoon.  All traffic has
> stopped and the mist hangs like a pall over everything.  Lights
> of ordinary intensity fail to pierce the fog, which is
> constantly growing heavier.
>
> "Scientists here are unable to agree as to the cause, and
> the local weather bureau states that the like has never occurred
> before in the history of the city.
>
> "At 7 P.M. last night the municipal authorities...
>
> (more)"
>
> That was all there was. Nothing out of the ordinary at a bureau headquarters, but, as I say, I noticed the story because of the name of the town.

Comment: Excellent research is always worthy of an upvote.

Comment: I take no small measure of pride in the fact that I've never held an answer back to farm rep for the following day

Comment: Thanks! Such a relief to finally have the answer. Grateful. Now to see if this story has held up from what my thirteen year old brain remembers.

Comment: Don't know if you spotted this or if it's of interest; https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41508421#41508421

Comment: @user14111 - Road trip!!!