# Short Story about Fog/Mist (Not Stephen King or John Carpenter)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story I read 10 years ago but which is significantly older than that.  It is similar to Stephen King's "The Mist"; in fact, I found it while looking into "The Mist".  But it is older.  A radio (or telegraph?) operator stationed on top of a skyscraper sees a mist or fog settle on his city.  Either the mist/fog or something in it is killing people (?, can't remember exactly what it is doing) and the operator can see it happening from above.  Again, not "The Mist" or "The Fog"; older than both.

Comment: ["The Night Wire"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?86054) by H. F. Arnold. See the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175352/telegrams-from-unknown-city-that-gets-destroyed-by-mist). The full text is available [here](http://doyleandmacdonald.com/l_nightw.htm).

Comment: You can listen to a reading [here](http://pseudopod.org/2013/10/18/pseudopod-356-the-night-wire/).

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!